# Firebase: REST API Auth via Query Parameter w Custom Token?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I have 20 enpoints that HTTP POST to my realtime database using the query parameter `"auth":"<db secret>"` and this works but I need to restrict access based on group.  There are 2 groups of 10 endpoints.

These (particle.io) endpoints can be hardcoded with the URL to POST to, query parameters, custom headers, etc, but I don't believe they can handle an HTTP response (get the token to use) without some additional firmware level coding.

Is it possible for me to manually mint a persistent (lifetime:0) token using the Firebase Admin SDK that I can then configure in my endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

You can [mint a custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) using Admin SDKs, but they are meant to be [exchanged for an ID token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#sign_in_using_custom_tokens_on_clients), which is what you must present when accessing the Firebase database. Plus, both custom tokens and ID tokens are short-lived (1 hour TTL).

If possible, you can run the Admin SDK directly on your devices with its [privileges restricted](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start#authenticate-with-limited-privileges) via database auth overrides. But this is not usually recommended, since the users on the device can simply disable that.

I think you will have to make some HTTP calls from your devices, if you're to make this work with access tokens.